# How to make a "Server too busy to handle your request" in PHP?

Tags: php, load, server-load

Right now I don't have time to optimize and to upgrade servers and once or twice a month the server reaches critical load (mysql basically) and it goes very very slow.

I want to show a static message saying the server is too busy when that happens.

How would I do that?

Comment: Is the server returning any of the standard error codes (e.g., 500)?

Comment: It sounds like you have a `SELECT` run amok and `JOIN`ing to too many data records or some variation thereof.

Comment: do you want to know how to show a static page with HTTP code, or how to detect when your server is slow?

Comment: @technoTarek no the server doesn't return any errors. Just takes like 5-6 seconds to show the page.

Comment: @eis Well, to show the static page I first have to detect when the server is slow, no?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-getloadavg.php ?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller wow, that easy? really? Post it as an answer if you want, I'll accept it

Comment: @Tebb from your original question it was quite impossible to say if you already know how to detect server load or not, or which part is the actual problem. But apparently the answer was 'both'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a function for that: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-getloadavg.php

example usage:

```
<?php
$maxLoad = 10;
$load = sys_getloadavg();
if ($load[0] > $maxLoad) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Too busy, try again later');
    die('Server too busy. Please try again later.');
}else{
    show_my_page();
}
```